# How to Get Font Names From Google Webfonts URL

Tags: javascript, fonts, google-font-api

Looking over the [Google Fonts API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api) and couldn't find anything that would allow me to get the font names for each font from a normal font link like this one.

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,700i|Merriweather:300,400,700,900i|Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300i,700
```

How can I get all the **font names** from a Google Webfonts URL?.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using code like the following.

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var googleFontUrl = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,700i|Merriweather:300,400,700,900i|Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300i,700';
var fontFamilies = getParameterByName('family', googleFontUrl).split('|');
var fontArr = [];
fontFamilies.forEach(function(item) {
  fontArr.push(item.split(':')[0]);
});

alert(fontArr.join(', '));
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5qvpg606/

Explanation:

1. First, retrieve value of the `family` parameter from the URL using the `getParameterByName` function. In this example, the value of the `family` parameter is "Droid Serif:400,700,700i|Merriweather:300,400,700,900i|Open Sans Condensed:300,300i,700"
2. Then split the value into an array to get the font families. We use JS String [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method with "|" as the separator. Now items in the array are: "Droid Serif:400,700,700i", "Merriweather:300,400,700,900i", and "Open+Sans Condensed:300".
3. Loop through the array, split each item (string) using ":" as the separator, get the first part (which contains family name) and push it to `fontArr`, so you'll get an array that contains "Droid Serif", "Merriweather", and "Open Sans Condensed".
4. To see the result, simply join the array: `fontArr.join(', ')`

Comment: Thank you for this, i'll try it out. Did you make this function or did you find it elsewhere? Would you mind explaining what's going on so I can understand it better?

Comment: I've added explanation. The `getParameterByName` function was taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript). The rest is my idea.

Answer (score -1):

1. Look: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans
2. Then select the font to use it.
3. Click: bottom right corner
4. Look: Specify in CSS.

Done!

Comment: You misunderstood. I'm looking to do this dynamically with any fonts selected, using javascript.

Comment: I see, I don't know a lot of js but if you can get the font-name of the url and raplace + with space, you could use that. Usin = and : as delimiters.